# Proving that $\mathrm{rank}(P_1+P_2) = \mathrm{rank}(P_1)+\mathrm{rank}(P_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Supposing $P_1$ and $P_2$ two projectors as: $P_1\circ P_2 = P_2\circ P_1$.

What is the condition for $P_1+P_2$ to be a projection?

If it was the case above then how can I prove that $\mathrm{rank}(P_1+P_2) = \mathrm{rank}(P_1)+\mathrm{rank}(P_2)?$

Comment: You can't, because it is not true. For a counterexample, take $P_1=P_2$.

Comment: But if $P_1+P_2$ is *also* a projection, that's another story.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Yes, in the case where $P_1 + P_2$ is also a projection, so what I frankly need is how to prove that $P_1 + P_2$ is a projection and the proving the identity in the above.

Comment: Consider that $(P_1 + P_2)^2 = P_1^2 + P_1 P_2 + P_2 P_1 + P_2^2 = P_1 + P_2 + P_1 P_2 + P_2 P_1$, together with the hypothesis you wrote...